# How to understand the dead person's future based on the life energy left through nava randhra marg?

Tags: death, moksha, atma, lokas

I heard, for a person based on his karma leaves the physical body through one of the nava randhra marg. It is said that if life energy/atma left the body through bramha randra then the person may attain mukthi/liberation.

Is it true? Can we estimate person's next birth or the loka to which the soul/atma goes after the death based on the nava randhra marg choosen? Which of those marg indicates what about a person's death?

Comment: No one knows which birth you will take after your death. Only the result of your karmas decide. Only advanced mystic Yogi's can arrange their time of death and attain moksha (if they want.)