# how will Kalki destroy all the bad people at the end of Kali Yuga

Tags: yuga, kali-yuga, kalki

It is said, after 4,32,000 years that the current Kali Yuga will end and then a new Satya Yuga will be created(as mentioned [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2875/what-exactly-happens-at-end-of-kali-yuga-how-will-the-world-be-destroyed)).

My question is

1)how will Kalki destroy all the bad people? [ is it by fire or water ]

2)Will the good people live for 1,00,000 years as they will be part of a new Satya Yuga?

3)Will all the current technologies like internet, planes & mobiles exist in the new Satya Yuga?

Comment: Hello! Your sub question 3 is scientific speculation. Scientific Speculation is off-topic on this StackExchange. Please consider removing that particular subquestion. [Here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)'s the official topic policy for reference.

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan If question 3 is Science based. Then what about [your question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/18347/according-to-scriptures-from-when-is-the-foetus-embryo-considered-to-be-alive) about "**embryo**", "**foetus**" et cetera? Why are you asking a Biology(Science) question? If you answer thus- **I am just asking about Hinduism view on birth cycle**. Then you should think over this- **The Questioner is also asking Hinduism views on- 'what will happen to these technologies.'**

Comment: Tell me where physical Internet or phones is even defined in any of the scriptures? Discussion of soul and its relation to the human body is of prime import in Hinduism. @AnuragSingh

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan Nowhere. And I agree with your comment fully. But please see this- **'Your question is about this- 'when foetus/embryo gets life'. This is "Biology"(excluding atma part), and thus is- Scientific and Off-Topic.'** Now if I stick to this statement, then in a sense every question on HSE is related to Science. But is it so? No. A science-based question looks different. Just by presence of some **"scientific" terms**, a question does not become science based. And it is not this hard as to recognize this- 'which question is science-based, which is not'.

Comment: But that question is specifically about the atman part. so your argument doesn't make sense. @AnuragSingh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the Partial answers for your questions:

1) Lord KALI Destroy all bad people when he appears:

> There are many incarnations of the Supreme Being as stated in Srimad-Bhagavatam (1.3.26): **“O brahmanas, the incarnations of the Lord are innumerable, like rivulets flowing from inexhaustible sources of water.”** However, out of all the various incarnations of the Supreme, the Srimad-Bhagavatam (1.3.28) specifically states “krishnas tu bhagavan svayam,” which means that Lord Sri Krishna is the original Supreme Personality of God.

2) Will the good people live for 1,00,000 years as they will be part of a new Satya Yuga?

> **"Lord Kalki will appear in the home of the most eminent brahmana of Shambhala village, the great soul Vishnuyasha.”** (Bhag.12.2.18)
>
> The Mahabharatra (Vana Parva, 190.93-97) adds to the description of Lord Kalki’s appearance: "Impelled by time, a Brahmana named Kalki Vishnuyasha will be born. He will possess great energy, intelligence and prowess. He will be born at a village called Shambhala in a blessed Brahmana family. As soon as thought of, vehicles, weapons, warriors, and arms and armors will all be at his command. He will be the imperial sovereign, ever victorious by the strength of his virtue. He will restore order and peace in this world, overcrowded with creatures and contradictory in its laws. That effulgent and greatly intelligent Brahmana will destroy all things. He will be the destroyer of all and He will be the maker of a new Yuga [Satya-Yuga]. That twice-born one surrounded by the Brahmanas, will exterminate all the low and despicable mlecchas wherever they will be found." So it explains Kali will destroy all and if need he is going to create people again with out any sins (He will establish moral law in the form of the fourfold varnas, or the suitable organization of society in four classes. After that people will return to the path of righteousness)

3) Will all the current technologies like internet, planes & mobiles exist in the new Satya Yuga?

> If Kali establish moral law and make suitable organization of society in four classes. After that people will return to the path of righteousness. I don't think so our current technologies like internet, planes & mobiles will not be  exist, it's going to be a creating new Yuga again based on his rules, thoughts and needs.

Answer (score 1):

Yudhisthira had the same question to Markandeya.

This is what Kalki will do before another Satya Yuga begins.

https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03189.htm

> And commissioned by Time, a Brahmana of the name of Kalki will take his birth. And he will glorify Vishnu and possess great energy, great intelligence, and great prowess. And he will take his birth in a town of the name of Sambhala in an auspicious Brahmana family. And vehicles and weapons, and warriors and arms, and coats of mail will be at his disposal as soon as he will think of them. And he will be the king of kings, and ever victorious with the strength of virtue. And he will restore order and peace in this world crowded with creatures and contradictory in its course. And that blazing Brahmana of mighty intellect, **having appeared, will destroy all things. And he will be the Destroyer of all, and will inaugurate a new Yuga.** And surrounded by the Brahmanas, **that Brahmana will exterminate all the mlecchas wherever those low and despicable persons may take refuge."**

---

He will later conduct a horse sacrifice.

https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03190.htm

> "Markandeya continued, '**Having exterminated the thieves and robbers,** Kalki will, at a great Horse-sacrifice, duly give away this earth to the Brahmanas, and having established anew the blessed rectitude ordained by the Self-create, Kalki, of sacred deeds and illustrious reputation, will enter a delightful forest, and the people of this earth will imitate his conduct, and when the Brahmanas will have **exterminated the thieves and robbers**, there will be prosperity everywhere (on earth). And as the countries of the earth will one after another be subjugated, that tiger among Brahmanas, Kalki, having placed deer skins and lances and tridents there, will roam over the earth, adored by foremost Brahmanas and showing his regard for them and engaged all the while in **slaughtering thieves and robbers. And he will exterminate the thieves** **and robbers** amid heart-rending cries of 'Oh, father--' 'Oh, mother!--'O son!' and the like, and O Bharata, when sin will thus have been rooted out and virtue will flourish on arrival of the Krita age, men will once more betake themselves to the practice of religious rites.

Kalki will exerminate thieves, robbers, mlecchas wherever those low and despicable humans may take refuge. The sin will be rooted out and virtue will flourish on arrival of the Krita age.