# is there any relation between Sperm and Human Soul?

Tags: atma, body, birth

is there any relation between human birth,soul and sperm?

If there is no relation when Soul enters in human body during pregnancy?

Comment: Last question already answered [In which month of pregnancy a soul enters in to a new body(foetus)?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/5488/5212). So remove it and focus on the main question i.e., relation between sperm, birth and soul.